# Gtsummary columns for all post hoc pairwise comparisons

Tags: r, gtsummary

Is there currently a way in gtsummary to create columns for the p values of each pairwise comparison for a post hoc test? For example, say there are 4 groups, is there a function that includes the p values as separate columns for

1. the overall anova or chi square depending on if continuous or categorical
2. a vs b
3. a vs c
4. a vs d
5. b vs c
6. b vs d
7. c vs d

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `add_stat()` function to add custom columns and rows to a `tbl_summary()` table. The example below uses the `pairwise.t.test()` to calculate the pairwise p-values (you can use whatever method you like).

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.5.0'
# set theme to get MEAN (SD) by default in `tbl_summary()`
theme_gtsummary_mean_sd()

# function to add pairwise copmarisons to `tbl_summary()`
add_stat_pairwise <- function(data, variable, by, ...) {
  # calculate pairwise p-values
  pw <- pairwise.t.test(data[[variable]], data[[by]], p.adj = "none")

  # convert p-values to list
  index <- 0L
  p.value.list <- list()
  for (i in seq_len(nrow(pw$p.value))) {
    for (j in seq_len(nrow(pw$p.value))) {
      index <- index + 1L
      
      p.value.list[[index]] <- 
        c(pw$p.value[i, j]) %>%
        setNames(glue::glue("**{colnames(pw$p.value)[j]} vs. {rownames(pw$p.value)[i]}**"))
    }
  }
  
  # convert list to data frame
  p.value.list %>% 
    unlist() %>%
    purrr::discard(is.na) %>%
    t() %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    # formatting/roundign p-values
    dplyr::mutate(dplyr::across(everything(), style_pvalue))
}

trial %>%
  select(grade, age, marker) %>%
  tbl_summary(by = grade, missing = "no") %>%
  # add pariwaise p-values
  add_stat(everything() ~ add_stat_pairwise) %>%
  as_kable() # convert to kable to display on Stackoverflow
```

| **Characteristic** | **I**, N = 68 | **II**, N = 68 | **III**, N = 64 | **I vs. II** | **I vs. III** | **II vs. III** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Age | 46 (15) | 48 (14) | 48 (14) | 0.6 | 0.4 | 0.8 |
| Marker Level (ng/mL) | 1.07 (0.89) | 0.68 (0.73) | 1.00 (0.92) | 0.010 | 0.6 | 0.040 |

<sup>Created on 2021-11-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Could you offer a solution that can be flexible for categorical AND continuous at the same time? I'd implement this myself, but it is not clear to me what I should be including in my if logic. Like `if is.numeric(var): do pairwise t tests, if is.factor(var): do chi square`. Specifically, what is the thing I can input in the `var` portion here? Once I have that it should be easy

Comment: ^^the method of using one function that uses same logic gtsummary uses to find if a variable is categorical vs continuous would be the correct answer, but as an alternative could you explain an alternative that works where you have 2 functions 1. one that uses the pairwise t test like you suggested and 2. one that uses a chisquare post hoc method like `chisq.multcomp` from the `RVAideMemoire` package. I'm struggling to implement the chisq.multcomp function as is because it is unclear to me how to take each row/variable in the table so I can then convert it to a matrix

Comment: you'll need to write a new function that uses `chisq.multcomp()` instead of `pairwise.t.test()` that prepares the output in the same way. Then update the `add_stat()` call to `add_stat(list(all_continuous() ~ add_stat_pairwise), all_categorical() ~ add_stat_pairwise_chisq))`

Comment: just added you to a chatroom. Would appreciate your insight so I can start making my own functions for gtsummary!

Comment: I'm not sure what that is FYI

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239652/gtsum here is the link!

Comment: ok I got the data by and variable usage I think. So It should be something like this `chisq.multcomp(table(data[[variable]], data[[by]]), p.method = "bonferroni")`. However, the rest does not seem to work. Returns an error of `Error: RHS of `location=` formulas must be one of 'label', 'level', or 'missing'`

Comment: @rj44 Did you figure out how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You have to re-implement the `chisq.multcomp` function from the RVAidememoire package to handle categorical variables, then call it in the newly created function `add_stat_pairwise_chisq()`. The implementation of the `chisq.multcomp` function is mainly to change the class of the result object to `htest` type. You can rely on the accepted answer for implementing the `add_stat_pairwise_chisq()` function.

```
library(gtsummary)
## Chisq_multcomp function reimplimentation
chisq.multcomp <- function(to_test, factor, p.method="fdr") {
    x <- table({{to_test}}, {{factor}})
    fun.p <- function(i,j) {
        xi <- x[I]
        xj <- x[j]
        suppressWarnings(chisq.test(c(xi, xj)))$p.value
    }
    tab.p <- pairwise.table(fun.p, colnames(x), p.adjust.method=p.method)
    call <- match.call()
    dname.x <- if(length(call$x)==1) {call$x} else {paste(call$x[1],"(",paste(call$x[-1],collapse=","),")",sep="")}
    result <- list(method="chi-squared tests", data.name=dname.x,p.adjust.method=p.method, p.value=tab.p)
    class(result) <- "pairwise.htest"
    return(result)
}

## Function to add pairwise comparisons to 'tbl_summary()'
add_stat_pairwise_chisq <- function(data, variable, by, ...) {
    # Calculate pairwise p-values
    pw <- chisq.multcomp(to_test = data[[variable]], factor = data[[by]], p.method = "none")
    # convert p-values to list
    index <- 0L
    p.value.list <- list()
    for(i in seq_len(nrow(pw$p.value))) {
        for(j in seq_len(nrow(pw$p.value))) {
            index <- index + 1L
            p.value.list[[index]] <- c(pw$p.value[i, j]) %>%
            setNames(glue::glue("**{colnames(pw$p.value)[j]} vs. {rownames(pw$p.value)[i]}**"))
        }
    }

    # convert list to data frame
    p.value.list %>%
    unlist() %>%
    purrr::discard(is.na) %>%
    t() %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    # formatting/rounding p-values
    dplyr::mutate(dplyr::across(everything(), style_pvalue))
}

# An example
trial %>%
    select(trt, stage, grade) %>%
    tbl_summary(
        by = grade, 
        missing = "no",
        statistic = all_categorical() ~ "{n}({p}%)",
        digits = all_categorical() ~ c(0, 2)
    ) %>%
    add_stat(everything() ~ add_stat_pairwise_chisq)
```

Answer (score 0):

For a dichotomous variable one could also do a pairwise.prop.test. The corresponding function for the table_summary would then look something like this:

```
gts_pairwise.prop.test <- function(data, variable, by, ...) {
  tbl = table(data[[by]], data[[variable]])
  pairwise.prop.test(tbl, p.adjust.method = "fdr") %>% 
    broom::tidy() %>%
    mutate(label = glue::glue("**{group2} vs. {group1}**")) %>%
    select(label, p.value) %>%
    spread(label, p.value)
}
```