# Gtsummary columns for mixed model p-value and interaction

Tags: r, gtsummary

I have been conducting a cross-over experiment, testing a specific treatment to a group of patients who received treatment "1" and "2" in random order.

I am fairly new to R, and I wish to generate a table with tbl_summary with one column of each treatment effect on various parameters, as well as a column for the p-value from the mixed model analysis (between-group comparison) and a sequence-interaction p-value.

I have calculated the between-period difference in response to treatment within each period by using a mixed model approach with the lme4-package. Then, I compared the treatment response between groups by the estimated marginal means (`emmeans`).
I have conducted my statistics using the following code:

```
library(emmeans)
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)

df <- data.frame (record_id  = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12),
                  treatment = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2),
                  treatment_sequence = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
                  treatment_response = c(-43.5, 135.0, 8.4, -7.2, 99.0, 159.0, 12.0, -27.0, 3.0, 12.0, -15.0, 91.5, 6.0, -9.0, 177.0, 27.0, 52.8, -54.0, -50.7, 63.0, -9.0, 186.0, -72.0, 15.0)
)
df

df_mm <- lmer(treatment_response ~ as.factor(treatment)*treatment_sequence + (1|record_id), data=df)
anova(df_mm)                       
emmeans(df_mm, list(pairwise ~ treatment), adjust = "bonferroni")
```

This gives the following output:

```
> df_mm <- lmer(treatment_response ~ as.factor(treatment)*treatment_sequence + (1|record_id), data=df)
> anova(df_mm)                       ###show model as anova???
Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
                                        Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF DenDF F value Pr(>F)
as.factor(treatment)                    1890.0  1890.0     1    10  0.4575 0.5141
treatment_sequence                       832.1   832.1     1    10  0.2014 0.6632
as.factor(treatment):treatment_sequence 7466.0  7466.0     1    10  1.8071 0.2086
> emmeans(df_mm, list(pairwise ~ treatment), adjust = "bonferroni")
NOTE: Results may be misleading due to involvement in interactions
$`emmeans of treatment`
 treatment emmean   SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
         1   1.45 19.9 19.7    -40.1       43
         2  61.83 19.9 19.7     20.3      103

Results are averaged over the levels of: treatment_sequence 
Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
Confidence level used: 0.95 

$`pairwise differences of treatment`
 1                       estimate   SE df t.ratio p.value
 treatment1 - treatment2    -60.4 26.2 10  -2.301  0.0442

Results are averaged over the levels of: treatment_sequence 
Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger
```

I would like the between-treatment comparison p-value (0.0442) along with the interaction p-value of 0.21 in the table. My aim is to create a table like this:

[image]

I have tried modifying the code from this post ([Gtsummary columns for all post hoc pairwise comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70129472/gtsummary-columns-for-all-post-hoc-pairwise-comparisons)), but I cannot seem to get it right.

Is this possible? And can someone help with the coding?

Comment: Please update your post with a minimal reproducible example, aka code and data we can run on our machines. Then we can help write the code to put this into the summary table

Comment: perhaps you need to use the summary() function on the second part of the emmeans results, which creates a data frame.

Comment: I have edited the post as requested @DanielD.Sjoberg. Thank you for the fast reply. I hope the code is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for updating. You're looking to report the treatment effect p-value from emmeans and the interaction p-value from the regression model?

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg that is correct.

Comment: Dear @DanielD.Sjoberg, did you have a chance to look at the code above?

Answer (score 1):

Below is a working example. BUT I don't think the emmeans method you're using is correct. If you want to use it, you'll need to update the code to grab the p-value from the emmeans object (it's just a random number for now).

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.6.1'

df <- data.frame (record_id  = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12),
                  treatment = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2),
                  treatment_sequence = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
                  treatment_response = c(-43.5, 135.0, 8.4, -7.2, 99.0, 159.0, 12.0, -27.0, 3.0, 12.0, -15.0, 91.5, 6.0, -9.0, 177.0, 27.0, 52.8, -54.0, -50.7, 63.0, -9.0, 186.0, -72.0, 15.0)
)

mod <- lme4::lmer(treatment_response ~ as.factor(treatment) * treatment_sequence + (1 | record_id), data=df)
tt <- emmeans::emmeans(mod, list(pairwise ~ treatment), adjust = "bonferroni")$`pairwise differences of treatment`
#> NOTE: Results may be misleading due to involvement in interactions
tt |> as.data.frame() |> dplyr::select(dplyr::last_col()) |> dplyr::pull()
#> [1] 0.04419325

car::Anova(mod) %>%
  broom::tidy() %>%
  dplyr::filter(dplyr::n() == dplyr::row_number()) |> 
  dplyr::pull(p.value)
#> [1] 0.1788567



my_custom_stats <- function(data, variable, ...) {
  formula <- 
    as.formula(glue::glue(
      "{variable} ~ as.factor(treatment) * treatment_sequence + (1 | record_id)"
    ))
  mod <- lme4::lmer(formula, data = data)
  
  # I think this is not appriraite due to the interaction
  # but if you're confident about this approach, update pw_difference_p to be from emmeans
  pw_difference_p <-
    emmeans::emmeans(mod, list(pairwise ~ treatment), adjust = "bonferroni") 
  pw_difference_p <- runif(1)
  
  interacton_p <-
    car::Anova(mod) %>%
    broom::tidy() %>%
    dplyr::filter(dplyr::n() == dplyr::row_number()) |> 
    dplyr::pull(p.value)

  dplyr::tibble(
    pw_difference_p = pw_difference_p,
    interacton_p = interacton_p
  )  
}


df %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by = treatment,
    include = treatment_response,
    statistic = all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ± {sd}"
  ) %>%
  add_stat(fns = ~my_custom_stats) %>%
  modify_header(interacton_p = "**Interaction P**",
                pw_difference_p = "**Treatment P**") %>%
  modify_fmt_fun(c(interacton_p, pw_difference_p) ~ style_pvalue) %>%
  as_kable()
#> NOTE: Results may be misleading due to involvement in interactions
```

| **Characteristic** | **1**, N = 12 | **2**, N = 12 | **Treatment P** | **Interaction P** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| treatment_response | 1 ± 60 | 62 ± 76 | 0.3 | 0.2 |

<sup>Created on 2022-08-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>