# Add group-wise statistical comparisons to gtsummary::tbl_continuous

Tags: r, gtsummary

Trying to add a column of statistical test results in gtsummary::tbl_continuous().
Here is an example:

```
library(tidyverse) 
library(gtsummary)

df <- tibble(
  Group = as.factor(c(rep('A', 8), rep('B', 8), rep('C', 8))),
  Variable = as.factor(rep(c(rep('x', 4), rep('y', 4)), 3)),
  Value = runif(24, 0, 10)
) 

df %>% 
  tbl_continuous(
    variable = Value,
    by = Variable
  ) %>%
add_p()
```

which produces:

[image: Output for tbl_continuous]

I would like to add t-tests (or more generally any appropriate test, ANOVA for instance if there were three columns) to the p-value column for each row to compare (x, y) between groups. I tried implementing the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70129472/gtsummary-columns-for-all-post-hoc-pairwise-comparisons) without success.