# How to add post hoc for categorical variables using gtsummary

Tags: r, gtsummary

I am new to R, so I apologize if this is a rather simple question.

part of my data is as follows

```
   pathogen abnorm B_Line consolid consol_size consol_sizeAdj
1  Bacteria    Yes    Yes      Yes          59          70.66
2     Virus     No     No       No           0           0.00
3     Virus    Yes    Yes      Yes          46          98.40
4        MP    Yes    Yes      Yes          45          89.55
5     Virus    Yes    Yes      Yes          43          63.47
6        MP    Yes    Yes      Yes          39          37.96
7        MP    Yes    Yes      Yes          37          45.26
8        MP    Yes    Yes      Yes          35          43.75
9  Bacteria    Yes    Yes      Yes          35          92.11
10       MP    Yes    Yes      Yes          35          26.12
11 Bacteria     No     No       No           0           0.00
12       MP    Yes    Yes      Yes          33          54.32
13    Virus     No     No       No           0           0.00
14 Bacteria    Yes    Yes      Yes          32          55.90
15       MP    Yes    Yes      Yes          31          30.69
16    Virus    Yes    Yes      Yes          30          48.00
17    Virus     No     No       No           0           0.00
18    Virus     No     No       No           0           0.00
19    Virus     No     No       No           0           0.00
20       MP     No     No       No           0           0.00
21    Virus     No     No       No           0           0.00
22 Bacteria     No     No       No           0           0.00
23       MP    Yes    Yes      Yes          24          23.36
24       MP    Yes    Yes      Yes          24          33.68
25       MP    Yes    Yes      Yes          22          45.36
26 Bacteria    Yes    Yes      Yes          27          33.75
27       MP    Yes    Yes      Yes          20          18.69
28       MP    Yes    Yes      Yes          20          26.14
29       MP    Yes    Yes      Yes          20          22.99
30       MP    Yes    Yes      Yes          19          17.59
31       MP    Yes    Yes      Yes          18          29.63
32 Bacteria    Yes    Yes      Yes          24          43.24
33       MP    Yes    Yes      Yes          17          23.29
34       MP    Yes    Yes      Yes          19          32.20
35    Virus     No     No       No           0           0.00
36       MP    Yes    Yes      Yes          15          14.35
37 Bacteria    Yes    Yes      Yes          15          22.14
38    Virus    Yes    Yes      Yes          15          30.93
39       MP    Yes    Yes      Yes          15          25.42
40 Bacteria    Yes    Yes      Yes          17          16.27
41       MP    Yes    Yes      Yes          14          26.92
42    Virus    Yes    Yes      Yes          14          15.47
43 Bacteria    Yes    Yes      Yes          13          20.80
44 Bacteria    Yes    Yes      Yes          13          23.42
45 Bacteria    Yes    Yes      Yes          12          20.34
46    Virus    Yes    Yes      Yes          12          26.67
47       MP    Yes    Yes      Yes          12          19.20
48       MP    Yes    Yes      Yes          33          61.40
49       MP    Yes    Yes      Yes          12          11.68
50 Bacteria    Yes    Yes      Yes          40          57.55
51    Virus    Yes    Yes      Yes          11          26.51
52       MP    Yes    Yes      Yes           7           8.75
53       MP    Yes    Yes      Yes          18          33.49
54       MP    Yes    Yes      Yes           9           8.41
55 Bacteria    Yes    Yes      Yes           9          14.81
56    Virus    Yes    Yes      Yes           8          10.46
57       MP    Yes    Yes      Yes          11          21.15
58       MP    Yes    Yes      Yes           9           8.33
59 Bacteria    Yes    Yes      Yes           7          12.61
60 Bacteria    Yes    Yes      Yes           7           4.40
61 Bacteria    Yes    Yes      Yes           7          11.86
62       MP    Yes    Yes      Yes           7          11.20
63    Virus    Yes    Yes       No           0           0.00
64    Virus    Yes    Yes      Yes           5          10.31
65    Virus    Yes    Yes      Yes           7          13.46
66    Virus    Yes    Yes      Yes           6          19.35
67    Virus    Yes    Yes      Yes           2           5.52
68       MP    Yes    Yes      Yes           6           7.50
69    Virus    Yes    Yes      Yes           6          19.35
70    Virus    Yes    Yes      Yes           6          10.81
71 Bacteria    Yes    Yes      Yes          26          50.00
72    Virus    Yes    Yes       No           0           0.00
73    Virus    Yes    Yes      Yes           5          12.58
74    Virus    Yes    Yes      Yes           5           6.85
75    Virus    Yes    Yes      Yes          10          18.02
```

I want to add p values for post hoc analysis with `add_stat` function from package `gtsummary` for my table 1(baseline). For reference, I found the answer to add p values for numeric variables, and just copied the code from:

[Gtsummary columns for all post hoc pairwise comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70129472/gtsummary-columns-for-all-post-hoc-pairwise-comparisons)

this is the code in the answer, and I want a categorical version of it

```
# function to add pairwise copmarisons to `tbl_summary()`
add_stat_pairwise <- function(data, variable, by, ...) {
  # calculate pairwise p-values
  pw <- pairwise.t.test(data[[variable]], data[[by]], p.adj = "none")

  # convert p-values to list
  index <- 0L
  p.value.list <- list()
  for (i in seq_len(nrow(pw$p.value))) {
    for (j in seq_len(nrow(pw$p.value))) {
      index <- index + 1L
      
      p.value.list[[index]] <- 
        c(pw$p.value[i, j]) %>%
        setNames(glue::glue("**{colnames(pw$p.value)[j]} vs. {rownames(pw$p.value)[i]}**"))
    }
  }
  
  # convert list to data frame
  p.value.list %>% 
    unlist() %>%
    purrr::discard(is.na) %>%
    t() %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    # formatting/roundign p-values
    dplyr::mutate(dplyr::across(everything(), style_pvalue))
}

trial %>%
  select(grade, age, marker) %>%
  tbl_summary(by = grade, missing = "no") %>%
  # add pariwaise p-values
  add_stat(everything() ~ add_stat_pairwise) %>%
  as_kable() # convert to kable to display on Stackoverflow
```

`chisq.multcomp()` was mentioned in the coment section, but I can't figure the way to write my own code.

I copied his code and tried writing something like this:

```
compare <- read.csv("final.csv", header = T)

add_stat_pairwise_numeric <- function(data, variable, by, ...) {
  # calculate pairwise p-values
  pw <- pairwise.t.test(data[[variable]], data[[by]], p.adj = "BH")
  
  # convert p-values to list
  index <- 0L
  p.value.list <- list()
  for (i in seq_len(nrow(pw$p.value))) {
    for (j in seq_len(nrow(pw$p.value))) {
      index <- index + 1L
      p.value.list[[index]] <-
        c(pw$p.value[i, j]) %>%
        setNames(glue::glue("**{colnames(pw$p.value)[j]} vs. {rownames(pw$p.value)[i]}**"))
    }
  }
  # convert list to data frame
  p.value.list %>%
    unlist() %>%
    purrr::discard(is.na) %>%
    t() %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    # formatting/roundign p-values
    dplyr::mutate(dplyr::across(everything(), style_pvalue))
}

add_stat_pairwise_categorical <- function(data, variable, by, ...) {
  # Calculate the contingency table and perform chi-squared test
  tab <- table(data[[variable]], data[[by]])
  chisq <- chisq.test(tab)

  # Extract the pairwise comparison p-values using chisq.multcomp()
  p.values <- chisq.multcomp(tab, reversed = TRUE)$pvals

  # Create a list of named p-values for each pairwise comparison
  index <- 0L
  p.value.list <- list()
  for (i in seq_along(p.values)) {
    for (j in seq_along(p.values)) {
      index <- index + 1L
      
      p.value.list[[index]] <- 
        c(p.values[i, j]) %>%
        setNames(glue::glue("**{colnames(p.values)[j]} vs. {rownames(p.values)[i]}**"))
    }
  }
  
  # Convert the list to a data frame and format the p-values
  p.value.list %>% 
    unlist() %>%
    purrr::discard(is.na) %>%
    t() %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    dplyr::mutate(dplyr::across(everything(), style_pvalue))
}

tbl_summary(
  data = compare, type = list(
    all_continuous() ~ "continuous2", 
    consol_size ~ "continuous2", 
    consol_sizeAdj ~ "continuous2"
  ), 
  by = pathogen, 
  statistic = list(
    all_continuous() ~ c("{mean} ({sd})", 
                         "{median} ({p25}, {p75})", 
                         "{min}, {max}"), 
    all_categorical() ~ "{n} / {N} ({p}%)"
  )
) %>% add_overall() %>%
  add_p(pvalue_fun = ~ style_pvalue(.x, digits = 2), 
        list(all_continuous() ~ "kruskal.test")) %>% 
  add_stat(list(all_continuous() ~ add_stat_pairwise_numeric, 
                all_categorical() ~ add_stat_pairwise_chisq)) %>% 
  modify_header(label = "**Severe**") %>% 
  bold_labels() %>% 
  modify_caption("**Baseline**") %>% 
  bold_p(t = 0.05)
```

but it doesn't work.

Result after using `add_p` function:

[the function I wrote for categorical variables doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4DZM.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is recommended to post a minimal reproduciable data example.

Comment: I updated my data and the code I wrote this post, can you review it for me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `add_p()` function from `gtsummary` calculates a test on continuous and categorical variables by default.

```
library(tidyverse)
data(mtcars)
as_tibble(mtcars)

# gtsummary
library(gtsummary)

mtcars %>% tbl_summary(by = am) %>% add_p()
```

[image]

```
mtcars %>% tbl_summary(by = cyl) %>% add_p(mpg ~ "aov")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But I have 3 groups, and I want to display post hoc analysis within these groups. How can I do that?

Comment: I added ANOVA to test `mpg` for three groups in `cyl`. You can ask for any common test in `add_p()`. See available methods here https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/tests.html What exactly do you mean by "post hoc analysis"?

Comment: I updated this post, can you review it for me?

Comment: Hi Keal. I'd recommend that you closed the old post and started a new one. When changing the code and question completely, there's potential confusion from my answer. I'd further recommend to ask Daniel D. Sjoberg directly for your request of all-vs-all pairwise comparisons by a factor variable. Best Marco