# Gtsummary columns for kruskall wallis post hoc pairwise comparisons (Mann whitney)

Tags: gtsummary, posthoc

I followed this answer to perform post hoc analysis in gtsummaey.
[Gtsummary columns for all post hoc pairwise comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70129472/gtsummary-columns-for-all-post-hoc-pairwise-comparisons)

I have some additional questions:

1. It does not work when replacing pairwise.t.test with wilcox.test (for non-normally distributed data) because the "by" variable has more than 2 levels.
2. I created a function as suggested in the link provided for testing categorical variables with chisq.multcomp but it did not work for me.
3. How can I bold_p in add_stat columns?
4. Lastly, modify_caption isn't saving with as_flex_table() %>% save_as_image.

reprex:

```r
library(reprex)
#> Warning: package 'reprex' was built under R version 4.2.3
library(dplyr)
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 4.2.3
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(gtsummary)
#> Warning: package 'gtsummary' was built under R version 4.2.3

# Create sample data
n <- 10
data <- data.frame(
  VAT_Quantile_3 = factor(sample(c("Low tertile", "Medium tertile", "High tertile"), n, replace = TRUE)),
  Gender = factor(sample(c("Male", "Female"), n, replace = TRUE)),
  Age = c(50.1, 49.2, 48.8, 51.7, 52.6, 50.4, 49.9, 48.2, 51.1, 52.7))


# function to add pairwise copmarisons to `tbl_summary()`
add_stat_pairwise_chisq <- function(data, variable, by, ...) {
  # calculate p-values
  pw <- chisq.multcomp(data[[variable]]~ data[[by]], p.adj = "bonferroni")
  # convert p-values to list
  index <- 0L
  p.value.list <- list()
  for (i in seq_len(nrow(pw$p.value))) {
    for (j in seq_len(nrow(pw$p.value))) {
      index <- index + 1L
      
      p.value.list[[index]] <- 
        c(pw$p.value[i, j]) %>%
        setNames(glue::glue("**{colnames(pw$p.value)[j]} vs. {rownames(pw$p.value)[i]}**"))
    }
  }
  
  # convert list to data frame
  p.value.list %>% 
    unlist() %>%
    purrr::discard(is.na) %>%
    t() %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    # formatting/roundign p-values
    dplyr::mutate(dplyr::across(everything(), style_pvalue))
}




# function to add pairwise copmarisons to `tbl_summary()`
add_stat_pairwise <- function(data, variable, by, ...) {
  # calculate p-values
  pw <- wilcox.test(data[[variable]]~ data[[by]], p.adj = "bonferroni")
  # convert p-values to list
  index <- 0L
  p.value.list <- list()
  for (i in seq_len(nrow(pw$p.value))) {
    for (j in seq_len(nrow(pw$p.value))) {
      index <- index + 1L
      
      p.value.list[[index]] <- 
        c(pw$p.value[i, j]) %>%
        setNames(glue::glue("**{colnames(pw$p.value)[j]} vs. {rownames(pw$p.value)[i]}**"))
    }
  }
  
  # convert list to data frame
  p.value.list %>% 
    unlist() %>%
    purrr::discard(is.na) %>%
    t() %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    # formatting/roundign p-values
    dplyr::mutate(dplyr::across(everything(), style_pvalue))
}


tab_1<- data %>%
  select(VAT_Quantile_3, Gender , Age) %>%
  tbl_summary(by = VAT_Quantile_3,
              statistic = list(
                all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})",
                all_categorical() ~ "{n} / {N} ({p}%)"),
              digits = list(all_continuous() ~ c(1, 1),
                            all_categorical() ~ c(0,1)))  %>%
  add_p(,pvalue_fun = ~style_pvalue(., digits = 3)) %>%
  add_stat(list(all_continuous() ~ add_stat_pairwise), all_categorical() ~ add_stat_pairwise_chisq)
#> Error:
#> ! Error processing `location` argument for element 'Gender'. Expecting a
#>   string as the passed value.
#> Backtrace:
#>      ▆
#>   1. ├─... %>% ...
#>   2. ├─gtsummary::add_stat(...)
#>   3. │ └─broom.helpers::.formula_list_to_named_list(...)
#>   4. │   └─broom.helpers:::.rhs_checks(...)
#>   5. │     └─purrr::imap(...)
#>   6. │       └─purrr::map2(.x, vec_index(.x), .f, ...)
#>   7. │         └─broom.helpers (local) .f(.x[[1L]], .y[[1L]], ...)
#>   8. │           └─... %>% cli::cli_abort(call = NULL)
#>   9. └─cli::cli_abort(., call = NULL)
#>  10.   └─rlang::abort(message, ..., call = call, use_cli_format = TRUE)


library(flextable)
#> Warning: package 'flextable' was built under R version 4.2.3
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'flextable'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:gtsummary':
#> 
#>     as_flextable, continuous_summary
tab_1 %>%
  as_flex_table() %>% 
  save_as_image(path = "t.png")
#> Error in .assert_class(x, "gtsummary"): object 'tab_1' not found
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>